# Friends and users table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to join users table and friends table.
My users ta le have username and password 
While friends table have  user_id1 and friend_id .problem is that i will recieve user id from sessions using username but how will i recieve the id of a friend that i want to add/follow.for example the user click on add friend button.i want to recieve two parameters user parameter and friend parameter.also please help me with the joining code of pivot table,how would i joinfriend table  user and friend id column with the user table..any hint will be helpful.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: How will i recieve the friend's parameters on clicking of add friend button.plz let me know.

Comment: @anmolhans how are you trying to get have you any code?

Comment: select u.user_id1,u.username,f.friend_id from users u left join friends f on u.user_id1= f.user_id1 where u.user_id1 = 'yoursessionuser_id1';

Comment: I am in the classroom i will show you the entire code in a while and try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Tables**

```
Users

id | name | email | details 
----------------------------
 1 | abc  | a@b.c | some detail
 2 | def  | d@e.f | some detail

Friendship

id | user_id | friend_id
-----------------------------
 1 |  1      | 2
 2 |  2      | 1
```

In the view where you have displayed users along with add to friend link. you will also pass the id of that user from the loop which you have used to iterate the users e.g

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) {?>
  <h2><?php echo $user->name?></h2>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url().'users/addtofriend/'.$user->id?>" class="btn btn-info"> Add to Friend </a>
<?php } ?>
```

In your Controller function you can get the user id from session and the user to be added to friend from url like

```
function addtofriend()
{
  $userId=$this->session->userdata['id'];
  $friendId=$this->uri->segment(3);
  // Call your model function
  $this->user_model->addFriend($userId,$friendId);
}
```

Comment: I would take user id from sessions but how would i recieve the friend id after clicking the add friemd button,this is my main concern.

Comment: you have never passed values in url?

Comment: Oh sorry.got it